# Count number of requests in a 24h range to determine user sessions?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Imagine a web server log containing lines like:

```
<timestamp> <ip> <user-agent> <product page>
```

I would like a report that

- count the number of requests for product page per user session within a 24h window with the following criteria:
- a unique user is defined as the combination of a number of columns ( )
- 24h window starts at the timestamp of first request for product page (24h window can start at any hour)
- in case there are more 24h lapsed between timestamp of requests it would be considered a new user session

For the following logs:

```
2019-1-1 01:00 1.2.3.4 Netscape product 5
2019-1-1 01:01 1.2.3.4 Netscape product 5
2019-1-1 01:00 1.2.3.5 Chrome product 5
2019-1-1 01:01 1.2.3.5 Chrome product 5
2019-1-1 01:59 1.2.3.4 Netscape product 5
2019-1-1 02:00 1.2.3.4 Netscape product 4
2019-1-1 02:01 1.2.3.4 Netscape product 4
2019-1-1 02:02 1.2.3.4 Netscape product 4
2019-1-1 07:43 1.2.3.5 Chrome product 5
2019-1-2  2:01 1.2.3.4 Netscape product 5
```

would produce:

```
1.2.3.4/Netscape, product 4, 1
1.2.3.4/Netscape, product 5, 2
1.2.3.5/Chrome: product 5, 1
```

and perhaps a second query would output:

```
1.2.3.4/Netscape, 6
1.2.3.4/Netscape, 1
1.2.3.5/Chrome, 3
```

(the number of requests per user 24h window, hence 1.2.3.4/Netscape is listed twice)

What would be example queries that would delivery both above result sets?

Bonus/optional: in case the requests within a 24h period are more than 30m in between it would be considered another new session

Answer (score 0):

here's something which may give you a direction (not necessarily too performant/efficient though, depending on the size of the input data set).

```
datatable(timestamp:datetime, ip:string, user_agent:string, product_page:string)
[
    datetime(2019-01-01 01:00), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-01 01:01), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-01 01:00), '1.2.3.5', 'Chrome',   'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-01 01:01), '1.2.3.5', 'Chrome',   'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-01 01:59), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-01 02:00), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 4',
    datetime(2019-01-01 02:01), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 4',
    datetime(2019-01-01 02:02), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 4',
    datetime(2019-01-01 07:43), '1.2.3.5', 'Chrome',   'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-02 02:01), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 5',
]
| extend user = strcat(ip, "/", user_agent)
| order by user asc, timestamp asc
| extend session_start = row_window_session(timestamp, 24h, 24h, user_agent != prev(user_agent) or product_page != prev(product_page) or ip != prev(ip))
| summarize session_count = dcount(session_start) by user, product_page
```

-->

```
| user             | product_page | session_count |
|------------------|--------------|---------------|
| 1.2.3.4/Netscape | product 5    | 2             |
| 1.2.3.4/Netscape | product 4    | 1             |
| 1.2.3.5/Chrome   | product 5    | 1             |
```

for the second query, the following could work:

```
datatable(timestamp:datetime, ip:string, user_agent:string, product_page:string)
[
    datetime(2019-01-01 01:00), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-01 01:01), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-01 01:00), '1.2.3.5', 'Chrome',   'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-01 01:01), '1.2.3.5', 'Chrome',   'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-01 01:59), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-01 02:00), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 4',
    datetime(2019-01-01 02:01), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 4',
    datetime(2019-01-01 02:02), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 4',
    datetime(2019-01-01 07:43), '1.2.3.5', 'Chrome',   'product 5',
    datetime(2019-01-02 02:01), '1.2.3.4', 'Netscape', 'product 5',
]
| extend user = strcat(ip, "/", user_agent)
| summarize count() by user, startofday(timestamp)
| project-away timestamp
```

-->

```
| user             | count_ |
|------------------|--------|
| 1.2.3.4/Netscape | 6      |
| 1.2.3.5/Chrome   | 3      |
| 1.2.3.4/Netscape | 1      |
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was not yet aware of row_window_session() :) Will give it a try! Could you suggest the required change to also incorporate the number of requests per window?

Comment: If you could specify the desired output in a form of a table (like done for the original question), that may help in understanding the requirement

Comment: I've just updated the original question to make it make clear, thanks for helping out!

Comment: Thanks answering. One question though.. the 24h window starts at the timestamp of first request... not when the day starts, so "order by startofday(timestamp)" is probably not the right approach.